# Is it bad to create a big array just to be sure?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a project for school. I implemented some arrays in my application to store some codes, so they are int arrays. The user of the program will import an excel sheet, and depending on the number of rows from the excel sheet, the program will generate codes. If the excel sheet as 5 rows, it will generate 5 codes, but if it has 5000 codes, it will generate 5000 codes.

I created an array of 99999 big with: `int[] name = new int[999999]` just to be sure, because I'm sure they will never go over 99999. Is that a bad way of coding? The program has to be efficient and stuff.

---

**Edit**: Thank you all very much. I already got a method which counts the number of rows in the Excel sheet but I didn't think of using `int[] name = new int[rows]`. Thanks a lot! And I will remember to use ArrayLists in the future! Thanks!

Comment: Create your array based on the size of the input.  Your method is brittle due to your assumption.

Comment: Plus, at 4 bytes per int, that's about 3.8MB just for that array. If every time you need a data structure, you create one that's way too big "just to be sure," then the first medium-sized program you write is going to fail for lack of available memory.

Comment: Use a `List<Integer>`, it's dynamically sized and thus correct for this problem.

Comment: Yes, it's bad. What you should do is, first get the number of rows that the excel sheet has and using that number you can define the array of that size.

Comment: You will later encounter `List` and `ArrayList`, for a growing array like data structure. For now take a realistic limit of say 500.

Comment: This will work until the most inopportune time. You should atleast catch when the program exceeded that value. If going to that trouble, then just do it right and use an ArrayList

Comment: An important lesson is that good and bad are always relative to what you want to achieve. Yes, in most "real-world" cases it would be considered pretty bad, however for a one-off school project that will read in a single Excel sheet, it probably is acceptable. A better, less subjective question would probably be: "How efficient is this solution?". And the answer to that would be that it's very inefficient. (But even then there are certain cases where pre-allocating a large buffer is the way to go.)

Comment: @biziclop And even then, there's another lesson to be learned, which is that things like "inefficient" can be measured in either relative or absolute terms. In relative terms, an array of size 999999 when you only have 5 elements is about 200,000x bigger than you need (!). In absolute terms... it's only 3.8 MB, which is probably also acceptable for a one-off school project _if_ the project explicitly doesn't care about memory usage (even a raspberry pi can spare 3.8 MB without breaking a sweat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you will be adding 99999 elements to the array every time, then this it would be fine. However, since it can happen that you only end up needing to store 500 elements in the array, then you have allocated a huge amount of space that will not be used.

In the case of the excel sheet, it is best to first check how many rows the excel sheet given has (from your post, it seems that the number of columns is irrelevant). That way, you can assign exactly the amount of space you need everytime, like this:

```
int[] name = new int[rows]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pre-allocating space for one million ints, you can start with a small array and then allocate new space as needed. Of course, [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will impact performance, so create the array as the user imports the data so you can create just the right size. For example if I want to store numbers in an array yet I do not know the input I can simply.

```
public class Arrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter number of elements");

    int n = input.nextInt();

    int arr[] = new int[n];

    System.out.println("enter elements");

    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){//for reading array
        arr[i]=input.nextInt();

    }

    for(int i: arr){ //for printing array

        System.out.println(i);

    }


}
```

This ensures that you never create more than you need and never have to little. So find a way to read the amount of excel tables when they are imported and create and array with that as it's size!